# Best approach to predict Brent barrel price? (GARCH, TARCH...?)

Tags: r, model, garch

I'm analyzing the Brent Barrel evolution over time (data attached to the question) from 1987 up to last week. It's weekly data, adjusted closing price every friday.

I'd like to carry out some forecasting on the evolution of Brent returns. So far, I've tried with a GARCH(1,1) and TARCH model, you can see here the graph of both.

**Given this data, which approach do you think is the best? A Garch(p,q) using any other lag, Tarch or another model?**

I attach here the code and the dataset I'm working out with.
Link to script: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hf1muwxghu6lqvn/brent.Rmd?dl=0

Link to the working environment with the data and functions: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q84lz6uye2wjlr4/datasetsbrent.RData?dl=0
[image: GARCH vs TARCH]

Comment: If you are asking questions about model selection, you should be asking over at [stats.se]. There is no specific programming question here so it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Be sure you make it clear how you are defining "best."

Comment: This appears twice on CV because you cross-posted and the SO post was bounced back. Cross-posting on SE is explicitly discouraged. Please read http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and then delete one of the posts!

Comment: If you want to predict price, you will have to use some conditional mean model. GARCH and its variations are conditional variance models. You can still use them but then you need to combine them with a conditional mean model.